# SQL Server Service does not start automatically after system restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server

I have a SQL Server system that reboots weekly (after installing Windows Updates).

The last three weeks I have seen that the SQL Server service does not start when the server comes back up (Configufation Manager shows the service as stopped) the System Event log shows the following errors:

Event ID 7000

> The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the
>   following error:  The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion.

Event ID 7001

> The SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service depends on the SQL Server
>   (MSSQLSERVER) service which failed to start because of the following
>   error:  The service did not respond to the start or control request in
>   a timely fashion.

Event 7009

> The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the
>   following error:  The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion.

However, I can start the service manually and it starts up fine.

The service is set to automatically start.

The SQL Server error log does not include any clues either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 14):

One issue that can cause this is that some systems, particularly VMs with the system volume on solid state storage, is that it boots up so fast and gets to the point of starting services before some of the networking has been fully initialized.  This, then, results in a failure of the service account authentication, and the service start fails accordingly.

To address this, set the SQL Server services to Automatic (Delayed Start).  This will put a 2 minute delay on starting them.  If 2 minutes is too much or not enough, you can [tweak it](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#SetDelayedStartTime) by changing `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\AutoStartDelay`, or you could create a Task Scheduler job that runs on Windows startup and continually attempts to start the services until they are started.

Comment: 5 minutes is not correct according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015189/automatic-vs-automatic-delayed-start/11015576#11015576

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Thanks--I was going off of my apparently faulty memory there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, the server is virtual but we never had any problems previously, nor do we on an identical staging server

Comment: This worked for me.  One thing I did in addition to this was setting the recovery options on the mssql service to automatically restart after a failure on intervals of fifteen minutes.